# How to fetch case sensitive data without using Upper, Lower, init cap functions in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a `transaction` table in which there is a column `trans_mode` which stores transaction mode for the transactions. Transaction mode contains one of the following values.

```
    trans_mode
    web
    app
    APP
    APP
    wEb
```

and there are are many more possibilities as `trans_mode` is varchar column.
I want to write a simple select statement like

```
select count(trans_mode) from tab where trans_mode='web';
or 
select count(trans_mode) from tab where trans_mode='Web';
```

Now, I do not want to use any condition like `upper(trans_mode)='WEB'` or `lower(trans_mode)='web'` or `any regular expression`, and output required is the count of `web` transactions ignoring the case.

I think we can achieve the same using "column format" when defining `trans_mode` column or by using some other method. However not sure. Please suggest.

Comment: You can put a trigger on the table, that lowers (or uppers) the values upon insert or update and then only use lower (upper) case in the query. You could also define a function based index on `LOWER(trans_mode)` (or `UPPER(trans_mode)`) and then use `LOWER(trans_mode)` (or `UPPER(trans_mode)`) in the query, if you are concerned about indexing here. You could also define s constraint checking, that `trans_mode = LOWER(transmode)` (or `trans_mode = UPPER(transmode)`. That forces the user to only enter lower (or upper) case strings, so that you can rely on that.

Comment: Column format AFAIK is just an SQL*Plus option for the display of data in that client. This won't help you for comparisons the server has to do.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that with a "column format", but you can change your current sessions' NLS behaviour:

```
ALTER SESSION SET nls_comp = Linguistic;
ALTER SESSION SET nls_sort = binary_CI;

select *
from tab
where trans_mode = 'app';
```

results in:

```
TRANS_MODE
----------
app       
APP       
APP
```

Online example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a0196bf8031e5c612b9a9f6a2de870e4

If you need the comparison to honor language specific comparison rules (e.g. `ß`  and `SS` should be treated the same in German), you can do that as well:

```
insert into tab values ('große');
insert into tab values ('GROSSE');

ALTER SESSION SET nls_comp = Linguistic;
ALTER SESSION SET nls_sort = XGerman_CI;

select *
from tab
where trans_mode = 'große'
```

returns:

```
TRANS_MODE
----------
große     
GROSSE
```

---

Starting with Oracle 12.**2** you can also use the `collate` option:

```
select *
from tab
where trans_mode = 'app' collate binary_ci
```

Comment: Surely, +1 for your answer. Nice solution. However, in this case, we need to alter the session every time. I want to make this easier.:)

Comment: @Tajinder: that or using `collate` in Oracle 12 are your only options.

Comment: Yes, thanks really helpful. I think in oracle 12.2 we can use collate at column level.

Answer (score 0):

Use COLLATE:

```
      select count(trans_mode) from tab where trans_mode='Web' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Will return web and wEb

Comment: That collation name is invalid for Oracle

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name collation may be invalid but collate isn't. I've used it in the past. Above is MS SQL...I think Oracle is slightly different syntax wise, but I'm sure he/she is smart enough to figure it out without me holding their hand.

Comment: The default Oracle sort is `Binary`, so they probably want `Binary_CI` for case-insensitive collation, as @a_horse_with_no_name mentioned in their answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 12.2 you can use `collate binary_ci` at column level.

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (
  id          NUMBER,
  trans_mode     VARCHAR2(4 CHAR) COLLATE BINARY_CI,
  CONSTRAINT t1_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

insert into transactions values(1,'web');
insert into transactions values(2,'app');
insert into transactions values(1,'Web');
insert into transactions values(1,'weB');

commit;

select count(0) from transactions where trans_mode = 'web' ;
```

Reference link:
https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/column-level-collation-and-case-insensitive-database-12cr2#column-level